# Leave a tensorflow (anaconda venv) script running on EC2 instance

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-ec2, ssh, anaconda

I'm trying to leave a script running on an EC2 instance after I close the SSH client. The script is running on an activated tensorflow_p36 virtual anaconda environment.

I have tried to use `screen` and `tmux` but to no avail ( I issue these commands when the venv is active). I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'` even though when I try `conda env list` I see that I'm using the `tensorflow_p36` environment.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `nohup {your command} &`?

This has previously worked for me.

Comment: I'll try it. Can you share your understanding on how the POSIX command nohup works in this situation? Also, what kind of results it yields when you relogin over ssh?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I am not certain how this command works. I am no expert on this topic, I was just hoping to provide you with a solution to your problem. I can say that when I re-login, I was able to see the process running, and monitor its output via the nohup.out file created by the command.

Comment: Use `man nohup` to find out more. Also `&` runs the command in a subshell, without the shell waiting for a return of 0. See `man bash`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and leave the thread open, in case someone that knows comes along.